# If the time hierarchy theorem holds relative to every oracle, what about a halting(RE) oracle?

Tags: time-complexity, halting-problem, oracle-machines

I may be misunderstanding this. But the halting problem ∈ RE-complete. P ⊂ RE EXP ⊂ RE. therefore EXP^RE = P^RE = RE(my logic might be(is probably)) wrong here, please edit it if it is to be right) Hopefully you get the idea.. Isn't the time hierarchy theorem supposed to hold relative to every oracle, but here it seems as if every single complexity class collapses into whatever class O(1) is. I'm probably wrong here in some context. I'm very new to this so if you down-vote please explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your reasoning is the precise definition of $RE$-completeness.

$RE$-complete is defined in terms of **computable** many-one reductions. This means that you may not be able to solve every question in $O(1)$ by applying the oracle, since you don't know how much time the reduction itself needs to take.

---

For completeness of the answer, on why we care about the type of reduction:

An oracle is defined to be a "black box" that can solve a single pre-defined language. For example, you can ask about an oracle to SAT, or Vertex-Cover. And you can ask about an oracle to the halting problem - but what you cannot do, is ask for an oracle of a family of languages. You might be confused since sometimes people say "oracle to NP" - what they really mean is an oracle to some NP-complete problem, say an oracle to SAT. Since NP-completeness is defined relative to polynomial reductions, this is not a problem to say you have an "oracle to NP".

Comment: But still this would imply that P = EXP relative to a halting oracle. Would it not? Unless it took greater then polynomial time to reduce an exp problem to the halting problem. Even if not you could get around this by replacing the halting oracle with a general RE oracle.

Comment: It can take more than poly time to reduce problems in EXP to the halting problem. And what do you mean by "general RE oracle"? An oracle is defined for a *single* language.

Comment: @Colonizor48 It would not. There is no way to get around the relativized time hierarchy theorem: no matter what oracle $A$ you pick, there will be no **efficient** reduction of $\mathsf{EXP}^A$ to $\mathsf{P}^A$. (Note that "$\mathsf{P}^A\not=\mathsf{EXP}^A$" is **different** from "$A$ computes a polytime-reduction of $\mathsf{EXP}$ to $\mathsf{P}$.")

Comment: @Noah Schweber What about an ALL oracle?

Comment: @Colonizor48 What *is* an "ALL" oracle? (No single oracle can compute all languages.)

Comment: @Noah Schweber ALL is the class of all decision problems. See https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:A#all. Saying that it just can't be an oracle seems a bit arbitrary.

Comment: @Colonizor48 It's not arbitrary at all. An oracle consists of **countably much** information (an oracle is a set of natural numbers, or something equivalent to that), and there are uncountably many decision problems. "ALL-oracle" is as meaningful as "the biggest natural number."

Comment: @Noah Schweber sorry for asking alot of questions. I don't know this very well but im trying to learn. Last 4 questions. 1, Why wouldn't a RE oracle work? Both EXP and P are in RE so why would you need to reduce them first? 2, What about an ELEMENTARY oracle? 3. Any resources where I can read more about oracles and complexity in general? I have numerous questions I haven't been able to find answers to but I don't want to get down voted into oblivion for posting them here. 4, Isn't it arbitrary to limit oracles to countable sets?

Comment: @Colonizor48 Embarrassingly, the downvote is my fault: I meant to upvote (this is a common subtlety) but misclicked. It's been too long for me to reverse the vote, but if you edit the question it will reopen it for me to change my vote to an upvote.

Comment: Re: 4 it's not arbitrary at all. An oracle by definition is something a Turing machine (or whatever model you're using) can send queries to; since Turing machines operate in a countable setting (e.g. finite binary strings), an oracle by definition has to be a countable set (e.g. a set of finite binary strings).

Comment: @Noah Schweber. I edited the question. Thanks for responding. I don't want this to go on too long in comments. If you have anything else to add feel free to chat.

Comment: @Colonizor48 An oracle is defined to be a "black box" that can solve a **single** pre-defined language. For example, you can ask about an oracle to SAT, or Vertex-Cover. And you can ask about an oracle to the halting problem - but what you cannot do, is ask for an oracle of *a family of languages*. You might be confused since sometimes people say "oracle to NP" - what they really mean is an oracle to some NP-complete problem, say an oracle to SAT. Since NP-completeness is defined relative to **polynomial** reductions, this is not a problem to say you have an "oracle to NP".